# Displaying parent attributes alongside child attributes

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, hierarchy

SSAS - Parent Child hierarchy - displaying other Parent attributes alongside Child Attributes

For example:

**Employee Table**

```
+-----+-------+------+---------------+
| KEY | NAME  | ROLE | MANAGERKEY    |
+-----+-------+------+---------------+
|   1 | John  | CAO  |             1 |
|   2 | Adam  | Emp  |             1 |
|   3 | Steve | CAO  |             3 |
|   4 | Colin | Con  |             3 |
|   5 | Tony  | Con  |             3 |
+-----+-------+------+---------------+
```

I've setup the Parent-Child relationship in the Dimension.

In Excel, when using Tabular view, I am able to see the following:

```
+-------------+-------+------+
| MANAGERNAME | NAME  | ROLE |
+-------------+-------+------+
| John        | John  | CAO  |
| Adam        |       | Emp  |
| Steve       | Steve | CAO  |
| Tony        |       | Con  |
| Colin       |       | Con  |
+-------------+-------+------+
```

I would like to see the Manager Role in the following, is this possible?

```
+-------------+-------+------+------------+
| MANAGERNAME | NAME  | ROLE | MANAGEROLE |
+-------------+-------+------+------------+
| John        | John  | CAO  | CAO        |
| Adam        | Emp   | CAO  |            |
| Steve       | Steve | CAO  | CAO        |
| Tony        |       | Con  | CAO        |
| Colin       |       | Con  | CAO        |
+-------------+-------+------+------------+

+-------+------+------------+
| NAME  | ROLE | MANAGEROLE |
+-------+------+------------+
| John  | CAO  | CAO        |
| Adam  | Emp  | CAO        |
| Steve | CAO  | CAO        |
| Tony  | Con  | CAO        |
| Colin | Con  | CAO        |
+-------+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

As you currently have your `Employee` table, you can't have a *Manager Role* attribute for an employee.

To have a *Manager Role* attribute, you'd have to add a `ManagerRole` column to your `Employee` table:

```
Key  Name   Role  ManagerKey  ManagerRole
---  -----  ----  ----------  -----------
1    John   CAO   1           CAO
2    Adam   Emp   1           CAO
3    Steve  CAO   3           CAO
4    Colin  Con   3           CAO
5    Tony   Con   3           CAO
```

... so that you could define a *Manager Role* attribute on your *Employee* dimension.